# Firebase Storage Url loading in a browser

Tags: browser, firebase-storage

How do you write the url of Firebase storage to show an  image in a browser?

because when i try to use this `gs://askdoctor-546bf.appspot.com/askdoctor/namasuba.jpg` it doesnt work , now which way should we view our images stored in the Firebase storage via url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example URL request from the documentation [Create a Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#create_a_reference)

`httpsReference = storage.refFromURL('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/b/bucket/o/images%20stars.jpg');`